# Comparar valores entre Array's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, jogos

Bom dia,
Meus caros, preciso de uma orientação sobre a comparação de valores entre duas Array's no JavaScript. Estou trabalhando em pequeno simulador de loteria onde o código inicia com a primeira Array contendo 6 números, a segunda Array vai armazenar os 6 números informados pelo usuário.

Até este ponto tudo ok, porém,é preciso comparar as duas Arrays e imprimir quantos e quais números foram acertados.
Será que alguém pode me dar um força nesse ponto do código.
Agradeço desde já toda atenção.

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/for-em-javascript-dica/28554

Comment: Olpa Jeferson, quando tiver uma dúvida sobre algo experimente postar a parte do código que você fez e o que você já pesquisou, perguntas vagas vão ter respostas vagas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta percorrer uma das arrays, verificando na outra se cada número da primeira está presente nela. Os números que baterem você pode guardar numa terceira array.

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, segue o exemplo mais básico, que utiliza um loop `for` (existem jeito mais elegantes, mas este é o mais tradicional e a lógica vale para muitas outras linguagens):

```js
var jogo = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55];
var sorteio = [9, 15, 16, 21, 35, 49];
var acertos = [];

// Verifica se cada número jogado
// está na lista dos sorteados
for(var i=0; i<jogo.length; i++) {
    if(sorteio.indexOf(jogo[i]) > -1) {
        acertos.push(jogo[i]);
    }
}

console.log("Você acertou " + acertos.length + " números: ", acertos);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que estava buscando....\m/

Answer (score 2):

Com as novas features do Javascript, vc consegue obter o resultado esperado utilizando o método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro):

```js
var jogo = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55];
var sorteio = [9, 15, 16, 21, 35, 49];
var acertos = [];

sorteio.filter(function(element) {
  if (jogo.indexOf(element) !== -1) {   // se for encontrado um valor nos dois arrays
    acertos.push(element)
  }
});

console.log('Os números que você acertou foram: ', acertos)
```

Assim também como o método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

```js
var jogo = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55];
var sorteio = [9, 15, 16, 21, 35, 49];
var acertos = [];

sorteio.filter(function(element) {
  if (jogo.includes(element)) {   // se for encontrado um valor nos dois arrays
    acertos.push(element)
  }
});

console.log('Os números que você acertou foram: ', acertos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Achei uma forma um pouco mais simples para utilizar o filter para esse objetivo.

O [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) verificar se o item existe ou não no array e retorna um boolean.

```js
const jogo = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
const sorteio = [9, 15, 16, 21, 35, 49]

const acertos = sorteio.filter(numero => jogo.includes(numero))


console.log("Você acertou " + acertos.length + " números: ", acertos)
```